# Inserting a Word Doc in Access OLE ObjectFrame is impossible because Word doesn't find ActiveDocument in its Document_Open

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, office-interop

I'm sorry if I’m posting here a very similar problem of the ones I already asked without success in [Access World](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/activedocument-doesnt-exist-only-when-ole-word-document-is-opened-from-an-access-form.327196/#post-1871651) and in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1218362/activedocument-not-found-only-when-ole-word-docume).

I'm thinking of a simple Access database to store Word Documents.

The Word Documents are based on a template called “*TestTemplate.dotm*”. Its **Document_New** and **Document_Open** have only one line: **Debug.Print ActiveDocument.FullName**.

The access database has:

- **One table** with only 2 fields: ID (autonumber), DocFullName (string).
- **One form**  with two text boxes (ID, FullName), one **UNBound ObjectFrame**.

The problem with the Word Documents based on “*TestTemplate.dotm*” is the following:

- **I can** open the file **from Word without errors**.
- **I can** open the file **from Access through my code without errors** (Context Menu or Command Button).
- **I CAN NOT** link the file to the **UNBound ObjectFrame** both at Form Loading or Current changing, **Word** will stop and throw the **error 4228** "*The command is not available because the document is not open*". For the Document_Open routine **there is no ActiveDocument opened**. Introducing a long delay or in the linking of the document (Access) or in the opening of document (word) doesn’t help.

It seems very strange to me that nobody else is incurring in this kind of problem:
filing Word documents in an Access database should be a very usual situation for Office Applications interoperability.

In [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1218362/activedocument-not-found-only-when-ole-word-docume) a inserted a link to a sample database and template. There I was trying a little more complex scenario with BoundFrameObject.

Thanks in advance, Lauro

Comment: After `.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 sFullName` don't you need to close the document?

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for your interest. I didn't close the the document, to leave the user the opportunity to edit it.